# Add timestamp to cell containing nested IF statments that will not change each time a Userform worksheet opens

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, timestamp, excel-2016

I am having difficulty getting a timestamp to remain static (unchanging) each time a worksheet derived from an Excel Userform is opened.  The goal is to have the cells in Column C provide a prefix and timestamp mmddyyhhmm (e.g., C106CS1130181200) that is determined by the information in Column G.

Currently, in "Sheet1", I have Columns A-G trying to workaround this problem.

Column A formula:

```
=IF(SurvData!G2="Confined Space Surveillance","C106CS",IF(SurvData!G2="Asbestos Surveillance","C106AP",IF(SurvData!G2="Electrical Frisking","C106EF",IF(SurvData!G2="Fall Protection Surveillance","C106FP",IF(SurvData!G2="Hearing Conservation","C106HC",IF(SurvData!G2="Tracked HM Storage Location","C106HM",IF(SurvData!G2="Hot Work Surveillance","C106HW",IF(SurvData!G2="Hexavalent Chromium","C106HX",IF(SurvData!G2="Hazard Communication","C106HZ",IF(SurvData!G2="Job Safety Analysis","C106JSA",IF(SurvData!G2="Lockout/Tagout Plus","C106LT",IF(SurvData!G2="Operational/Out of Service","C106OOS",IF(SurvData!G2="Lead Surveillance","C106PB",IF(SurvData!G2="Personal Protection Equip","C106PPE",IF(SurvData!G2="Respiratory Protection Surveillance","C106RP",IF(SurvData!G2="Shop Safety Surveillance","C106SI",IF(SurvData!G2="Ship Safety Surveillance","C106SS","")))))))))))))))))
```

Column B Formula: is identical to Column A

Column C Formula:
`=IF(B2="","",timestamp())`

Column D Formula:
`=IF(AND(SurvData!C2<>"",SurvData!G2<>""),Sheet1!B2&C2,SurvData!C2)`

Column F Formula:
`=CONCATENATE(A2,C2)`

The worksheet labeled SurvData Column C cells contain a formula to get the result of a Serial ID from Column F, Sheets1.  Regardless of my efforts, the timestamp seems to change when the SurvData worksheet is opened.

Is there a way to write VBA in a Worksheet Change event that would allow me to combine the nested IF() Statement above with a timestamp and have it remain static (non-changing)?

Comment: Can you instead just use a `VLOOKUP()` formula instead of that long `IF()` formula?

Comment: You can do a value transfer or paste formulas as values. This will keep the time stamps constant until the macro is told to change them

Comment: BruceWayne,  I don't know if a VLOOKUP() would solve this problem.  Could you explain your thought on using the VLOOKUP()?  I'm using the nested IF() statement to determine what has been selected from a drop-down menu in a Userform, that is loaded into Column G cells each time the macro loops to add new rows as data gets entered on the form.  Where would the VLOOKUP() search.  Maybe I'm over thinking it.

Comment: urdearboy,  I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean.  Currently the formulas are pasted into each cell within the respective columns.  Unfortunately, each time the worksheet is opened, all the timestamps update with the new time/date (undesired result).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish this. The first is using a timestamp formula.

This will work:

```
=IF(TargetCell<>"",IF(TimestampCell<>"",TimestampCell,NOW()),"")
```

For this to work you will need to enable circular references. To do that head to the options in excel -> Formulas -> Check the box that says "Enable Iterative Calculation".
That will create a timestamp in a cell as soon as the target cell is changed. However, I **strongly** urge you to create one single cell in your sheet and have it contain the formula `=NOW()` and have every other formula that needs the current time to reference that cell.

Create a list of strings, possible entries for what would appear in the G column. Do this in a separate worksheet. Then add the list of codes the strings mean next to it. Do a `VLOOKUP` or do `INDEX/MATCH` and pull the answer. Something along the lines of `=INDEX('NewLookupSheet'!$A$1:$B$17,MATCH('SurvData'!G2,'NewLookupSheet'!$A$2:$A$17,0),2)`

To provide a VBA solution, I would need more information to edit this and update the answer. As it stands, there is no clear VBA solution to provide other than pseudo-code as there is no clear information on what has already been attempted or what the VBA is attempting to accomplish differently from a formula solution.